# Semifields of order 8 are fields

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

I need to proof that semifields of order 8 are all fields. (S, +, *) is semifield if:
1) (S, +) is abelian additive group
2) (S \ {0}, *) is a loop
3) left and right distributive properties:
(a + b)*c = ac + bc
c*(a+b) = ca + cb

Loop is a quasigroup with e.
I'll be grateful if you give me any hints. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(not a full answer)*

Let $S$ be a semifield with $8$ elements.

Because of distributivity, we have 
$$((1+1)\cdot(1+1))\cdot(1+1)=1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=0$$
so $1+1$ can't be in the multiplicative loop, hence $1+1=0$ and consequently $x+x=0$ for each $x\in S$.

Now let $a\in S\setminus\{0,1\}$ be arbitrary.
We have $a\cdot a\ne a$ (since $a\cdot x=a$ has the unique solution $x=1$), $a\cdot a\ne 1$ (since then $a\cdot (a+1)=a+1$), and if $a\cdot a=a+1$, we would receive a subfield $\{0,1, a, a+1\}$ over which $S$ would be a vector space, but that's impossible as $8$ is not a power of $4$.

Consequently, the following $8$ elements are different, hence
$$S=\{0,\,1,\,a,\,a+1,\,a^2,\, a^2+1,\, a^2+a,\, a^2+a+1\}$$

Now we can continue analyzing the possibilities for $a^2a\, =(a\cdot a)\cdot a$ and $aa^2 \, =a\cdot (a\cdot a)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I proved thad a^2 * a and a * a^2 may be equal to a + 1 or a^2 + 1. Do you have ideas how to prove that they should be equal to the same thing?